# Unable to push or pull with Bitbucket

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I'm having some issues with Bitbucket.

I've been trying to get more fancy with my git usage, and managed to get some errors. First it was a merge conflict, resolved that. 
But ever time I do a git push i get this error:

```
fatal: The current branch development has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

git push --set-upstream origin development
```

I tried to resolve that to, but now I only get this:

```
fatal: unable to connect to bitbucket.org:
bitbucket.org[0: 131.103.20.168]: errno=Connection refused
bitbucket.org[1: 131.103.20.167]: errno=Connection refused
```

The ip addresses appear to be Bitbucket's own.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to edit the .git/config file  and from there delete the Bitbucket parts. 
Then to add this:

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:username/file.git
```

before doing:

```
git push -u origin --all
```